# как добавить класс на элемент и на другой элемент не удаляя предыдущий

Tags: javascript

Вопрос заключается в том что бы при нажатии на элемент добавлялся класс и при нажатии на другой элемент добавлялся класс и также при нажатии удалялся

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
    <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <meta content="description" name="description" />
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />

    <title>Title page</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="info__title">
          Менеджеры для отобржения в визитке компании
        </div>
        <div class="all-managers">
          <div class="all-managers-item">
            Иванов Иван
            <img class="plus" src="./img/plus.svg"/>
            <img class="close" src="./img/close-wh.svg" />
          </div>
          <div class="all-managers-item">
            Петров Петр
            <img class="plus" src="./img/plus.svg"/>
            <img class="close" src="./img/close-wh.svg" />
          </div>
          <div class="all-managers-item">
            Константинопольский Константин
            <img class="plus" src="./img/plus.svg"/>
            <img class="close" src="./img/close-wh.svg" />
          </div>
          <div class="all-managers-item">
            Сидоровский Александр
            <img class="plus" src="./img/plus.svg"/>
            <img class="close" src="./img/close-wh.svg" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const els = document.getElementsByClassName('all-managers-item');
const className = 'open';
for (let i in els) {
  els[i].onclick = function() {
    els[i].classList.contains(className) ?   els[i].classList.remove(className) : els[i].classList.add(className) 
  }
}
```

Comment: можешь пояснить пожалуйста

Comment: Вешаешь на элемент событие клика мышки. Тот в свою очередь будет проверять наличие класса. Если есть, удалять, нет, добавлять.
А лучше покажи свой код с html и js

Comment: добавил фото  html  кода

Comment: Смеешься? Давай код html и js(если есть) в виде текста.

Comment: вроде бы добавил код
извини если что первый раз тут

Comment: Супер! На какой элемент надо нажимать, что бы добавлялся класс и как он называется?

Comment: элемент с классом all-managers-item
класс который добавляется называется open

Comment: Добавьте этот код в ваш test.js (Код в ответе изменил)

Comment: все работает) спасибо большое , очень благодарен

Comment: учеником вашим можно стать ?)

Comment: Да пожалуйста )
Если ответ устраивает, жми галочку принять ответ.
По общим правилам - один вопрос по коду - один пост!

Comment: может в тг для удобства ?

Comment: Не! Тут не так много народа, а развивать stack на русском надо )
Так что пиши вопросы сюда

Comment: ладненько) спасибо